# Convert AS2 code to AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript-2

I have never worked with AS2 and I was wondering how you would convert this to AS3? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
stop();
var nr:Number = 0;
var $mc:MovieClip;

this.onEnterFrame = function (){
    if(nr < 100)
    {
            $mc = this.attachMovie("fire", "fire"+nr, nr);
            $mc._x = random(4)-2;
            $mc._yscale = 80;
            $mc._rotation = random(2)-1;
            random(2) == 0 ? $mc._xscale = 80:$mc._xscale = -80; 
            nr++;
    } else {
        nr = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: In the future, it would be best to show what you've already tried and then focus your question on the parts that you can't figure out on your own.

Answer (score 0):

See the inline comments in the re-factored code below:

```
stop();
var ctr:int = 0;  //var to keep track of how many instances you've made of the Fire class 
var mc:DisplayObject;  //temporary object to hold the created instance of the FIre class

this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onEnterFrame); //this is how you do enter frame handlers in AS3

function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void {
    if(ctr < 100)
    {
            /*
               instead of doing the attach movie clip, you have give your Fire object it's own class / actionscript linkage, then you instantiate it and add it to the display list with addChild()
            */    

            mc = new FireClass();
            mc.x = random(4)-2;   //in AS3 there is just Math.Random(), which returns a number between 0 and 1.  I've made a random() function below that emulates the old random() function.  Also, ._x & ._y are now just .x & .y
            mc.scaleY = .8;  //scaleX/Y have changed names, and 0 - 100 is now 0 - 1.
            mc.rotation = random(2)-1;
            mc.scaleX = random(2) == 0 ? .8 : -.8; 
            addChild(mc);
            ctr++;
    } else {
        this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onEnterFrame); //remove the listener since ctr has reached the max and there's no point in having this function running every frame still
    }
}

function random(seed:int = 1):Number {
    return Math.Random() * seed;
    //if you're expecting a whole number, you'll want to to this instead:
    return Math.round(Math.random() * seed);  //if seed is 4, this will return 0,1,2,3 or 4
}
```